# Combine array elements into string php

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de concatenar un array dentro de un string, pero quiero que el string imprima algo como esto "'Se oferta','Vigente','Inactiva','Cerrada'" pero me esta imprimiendo esto "'Se oferta,Vigente,Inactiva,Cerrada'", ya he intentado de mil forma y no lo consigo 
Este es mi codigo, ya tambien lo intente con un for y es el mismo resultado

$oferta=$_POST["oferta"];
$sql2 = " '".implode("'".","."'",$oferta)."'";

Comment: Esto: `$sql2 = " '".implode("'".","."'",$oferta)."'";` debería producir la salida que quieres, que sería esta: `'Se oferta','Vigente','Inactiva','Cerrada'`, si he entendido bien. Ahora bien, debes revisar qué hay realmente en `$_POST["oferta"]`.

Comment: Acabo de resolver el problema, gracias :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código debería funcionar bien, si **realmente**  en `$_POST["oferta"];` los datos están bien.

Vamos a simularlo y verás que funciona:

```
$_POST=array("oferta"=>array('Se oferta','Vigente','Inactiva','Cerrada'));

$oferta=$_POST["oferta"]; 
$sql2 = " '".implode("'".","."'",$oferta)."'";
echo $sql2;
```

**Salida:**

```
 'Se oferta','Vigente','Inactiva','Cerrada'
```

Si no te funciona, deberías verificar lo que hay en el POST con algo como:

```
var_dump($_POST["oferta"]);
```

La salida debería ser algo así:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Se oferta"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Vigente"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "Inactiva"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "Cerrada"
}
```

Otra forma de hacerlo, si te sirven los datos mismos del array con prefijo y sufijo, sería pasando cada elemento como referencia con `&`.

Este código **modifica** los elementos del array:

```
#Aquí & significa que pasamos por referencia, por tanto los cambios afectan al elemento
foreach ($oferta as &$item){
    #Modificamos cada elemento poniéndole '  como prefijo y sufijo
    $item="'$item'";
}
echo implode(",",$oferta);
```

**Salida:**

```
'Se oferta','Vigente','Inactiva','Cerrada'
```